# Referring to a nested resourse

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, haml

I have a nested resource:

```
  resources :res1 do
    resources :res2

  end
```

And I have a **custom** action in res2:

```
def my_action

end
```

which doesn't appear in the list of the pre-generated paths (there is no `res1_res2_my_action_url` url). I want to refer to `my_action` using **controller** and **action** notation but the following doesn't work:

```
url_for(controller: [:res1, :res2], action: :my_action)
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

The `resources` directive in your routes file will only create default routes for your controller.

```
#index
#new
#create
#show
#edit
#update
#destroy
```

If you want to add custom routes, you'll have to declare them like so:

```
resources :res1 do
  resources :res2 do
    get :my_action
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

you can hard code a specific route that points to `action` and `controller`:

```
get '/pathname', to: 'controller_name#my_action'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running `rake routes` and see what o/p you get,a try to apply in your view

```
get 'my_action' => "res2#my_action"
```

and then write

```
:url => my_action_path
```